# Is it possible for Seer to use the -ga magick?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-a2

Can the Seer use the -ga (Firaga/Thundaga/Blizzaga) magicks learnt from being a Black Mage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Seer's skillset includes Fira, Blizzara, and Thundara as the only black magicks. A Seer can still use Firaga, Blizzaga, and Thundaga by having Black Mage as its subclass.